# Unknown manufacturer type when controlling TV using IR LED

Tags: arduino, television, arduino-nano

I am trying to make a system where I can control my TV using an IR LED with an arduino nano or uno. I have been able to get my TV to turn off and on, as well as a few other function that are related to the TV specifically. However, I can't find out how to control the cable (channels) with the LED. When I try to find out the manufacturer (so I know which "send__()" to use), I am getting responses of "unknown". This is the code I am using:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
 
// Define sensor pin
const int RECV_PIN = 4;
 
// Define IR Receiver and Results Objects
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
 
void setup(){
  // Serial Monitor @ 9600 baud
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Enable the IR Receiver
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
}
 
void loop(){
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
        Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
        switch (results.decode_type){
            case NEC: 
              Serial.println("NEC"); 
              break;
            case SONY: 
              Serial.println("SONY"); 
              break;
            case RC5: 
              Serial.println("RC5"); 
              break;
            case RC6: 
              Serial.println("RC6"); 
              break;
            //case DISH: 
            //  Serial.println("DISH"); 
              break;
            case SHARP: 
              Serial.println("SHARP"); 
              break;
            case JVC: 
              Serial.println("JVC"); 
              break;
            //case SANYO: 
            //  Serial.println("SANYO"); 
              break;
            //case MITSUBISHI: 
            //  Serial.println("MITSUBISHI"); 
              break;
            case SAMSUNG: 
              Serial.println("SAMSUNG"); 
              break;
            case LG: 
              Serial.println("LG"); 
              break;
            case WHYNTER: 
              Serial.println("WHYNTER"); 
              break;
            //case AIWA_RC_T501: 
            //  Serial.println("AIWA_RC_T501"); 
              break;
            case PANASONIC: 
              Serial.println("PANASONIC"); 
              break;
            case DENON: 
              Serial.println("DENON"); 
              break;
          default:
            case UNKNOWN: 
              Serial.println("UNKNOWN"); 
              break;
          }
        irrecv.resume();
 }
}
```

(note this is not my code, I have modified it from something I found online).

When I hit any buttons that control my cable, I get strange responses in the serial monitor. I get things like this:

37910D
UNKNOWN
FFFFFFFF
UNKNOWN
37111D
UNKNOWN
FFFFFFFF
UNKNOWN

Is there any way I can still control the cable of the TV with the LED? I read that you can send values raw, but I didn't understand how I do this. For example, the TV which is sony needs each signal to be modulated three times. How would I know if something similar needs to be done with my cable? If you have any ideas on how I could send the signal, or on other ways I could control the cable with an ir LED, I would love to hear them.

Thanks in advance.